# GDB step (in) isn't working for std::string

Tags: c++, gdb, cgdb

Using GDB (CGDB) I can step into the code of C++ standard library containers such as `std::vector` or `std::set`, but not `std::string`. Does anyone know why? Can I somehow enable this? I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::vector<double> v;
  std::set<double> s;
  std::string str;
  return 0;
}
```

For example, after compiling the code above with `g++ -g debug.cpp`, I can step into the `std::vector` and `std::set` constructors (and base class constructors etc.), but not `std::string`.

Comment: How did you compile? I had this pain with my functions taking std::string as argument. Couldn't step inside with `s` but had to set a breakpoint inside the functions instead then and simply `continue`.

Comment: @TonyTannous: from the post: "... after compiling the code above with `g++ -g debug.cpp`, ..."

Comment: @Fred Larson. Can't believe I missed that :D

Comment: @TonyTannous: I can't tell you how many times I've failed reading comprehension on this site.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know why?

This is happening because `std::vector` and `std::set` are templated classes which are (necessarily) defined in header files, while `std::string` is not.

In order to avoid repeatedly compiling `std::string` methods in each `.cpp` file, these methods are defined in `libstdc++`.

You can't step into them because you haven't installed `libstdc++` debuging symbols package.

> Can I somehow enable this?

Yes: install the debug info for `libstdc++`, appropriate for your system. On my (Debian) system that's `libstdc++6-dbgsym`, and with it installed, you would see something like:

```
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdc28) at t.cc:9
9        std::string str;
(gdb) s
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string (this=0x7fffffffdaa0) at /build/gcc-10-R1sACw/gcc-10-10-20200324/build/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:433
433     /build/gcc-10-R1sACw/gcc-10-10-20200324/build/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h: No such file or directory.
```

Now, this is still pretty bad, because it refers to *temporary* build directory which doesn't exist anywhere, except on the maintainer system.

But you can use GDB `dir` command to point GDB to appropriate source directory (which you can obtain by installing source package for `libstdc++`).

P.S. You could also avoid this problem by building your own `g++` version, but that may be more trouble than it's worth.

P.P.S. It's very rare that you *actually* need to step into `std::string` (or any other `std::` methods. Most of the time you can just assume that they work correctly, and/or look at the source to see how they are implemented.

Comment: Thanks, that makes total sense. I should have mentioned that I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. There is no `libstdc++6-dbgsym` package there; nor a libstdc++ package containing the string "dbgsym". I have GCC version 9.3.0, and already had `libstdc++-9-dev` installed. I noticed some packages with the `(debug build)` comment...but there is no `libstdc++-9-dbg`. (I do often build my own GCC, but I'd like to know how to do this using standard packages.)

Comment: ...there is though a `libstdc++-6-9-dgb` package on Ubuntu. After executing`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug` GDB will step into `std::string`, but showing machine code rather than source code. I haven't found an Ubuntu source package for libstdc++ yet.